# How to add column of SUM (in data grid view) to sum data from releation of other data table?

Tags: c#, postgresql, datagridview, sum

Ok so I have two tables.

First one is "Service" which contains information about Car, date, employee working on car, and so on.

2nd table is "service journal". It contains this:

`ID       ID_Service      Text       Price`

`1          1             blabla      50`

`2          1                gfdgfd   75`

Both tables have they own data grid view.

I want to add column "Sum" at first datagrid, which shows sum of all prices. For this example it would be 75.

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to first write an SQL query which returns that data.

Comment: Just small questions. 'Service journal' contains all repairs done on  all cars whitch have ever been in service, or it's just price list?

Answer (score 1):

If "Service journal" means "price list", try to write this query:

```
SELECT ..., SUM([Price]) FROM xyz WHERE ID_Service=x OR ID_Service=y
```

And than use Eval in column settings and than you'll have generated new column whitch will be named as "Columnx" where x equals index of column in query.
You must use WHERE...OR... for selecting all things that have been done on car.

Or if "Service journal" means list of all repairs done on all cars whitch have ever been done in service, try to write this query:

```
SELECT ..., SUM([Price]) FROM Service_journal WHERE ID_Service=CarServiceNumber
```

This SQL query will get summary of prices of all services/repairs whitch have been done. This query is based on understanding of ID_Service in that it means id whitch is common for all repairs done on one car.

Bit unclear question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Im working in kinda "offline" mode, can I do some querys to get info out of data tables? Also how do I add column to datagrid to show the query data (if I need to use it)

Comment: are you using Visual Studio? If yes, go to page designer, click on black arrow in top-right corner and edit columns, or edit sql data source. If you're using only C# code to create and manage DataGridViews, try to add column via class and set datafield property of the column.